# Kill or interrupt dispatch_queue_t method

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

Using this code I can execute a my code in background.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            // Perform async operation
            // Call your method/function here
            // Example:
            // NSString *result = [anObject calculateSomething];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update UI
                // Example:
                // self.myLabel.text = result;
            });
        });
```

But I can't find a solution to interrupt this background thread. Is there any method to kill or interrupt a queue?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are trying to achieve. From your description of problem I just can tell, that you are going in wrong way.

Comment: @Cy-4AH , I have to kill the thread when the user presses the HOME button

Comment: Who have told you that? System will pause yours application threads, except cases when you have requested some background activities: background task, fetches, etc.

Comment: @Cy-4AH ,thanks. Anyway, I have to create another user interaction where I have to use thread cancel option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use `NSOperationQueue` to manage your code flow and create your `NSOperation` instances to respect the `cancelled` property. Once you have done this you can easily suspend the queue (to pause execution of future operations) and cancel any (or all) operations.

Note that it is your responsibility to write your operation to be cancellable - it needs to decide at which points during its processing it's sensible to check the status of `cancelled` and abort further processing.

Comment: Can you provide some simple example?

Comment: there are certainly a good number of intro guides to `NSOperationQueue` on the web if you haven't used it before, it's a blog post rather than an answer...